# How to make Bulma card images same height inside columns of different width?

Tags: css, bulma

I am trying to make two cards inside columns of width 7 and 5. I want to have the card images same height. How can I achieve that?

I have tried classes like is-fullheight and set the card height to 100%, but it does not work that way.

```
            <div class="columns is-fullheight">
                <article class="column is-7">
                    <div class="card is-fullheight">
                        <div class="card-image">
                            <figure class="image is-4by3">
                                <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png" alt="Placeholder image">
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-content">
                            <div class="media">
                                <div class="media-left">
                                    <figure class="image is-48x48">
                                        <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/96x96.png"
                                            alt="Placeholder image">
                                    </figure>
                                </div>
                                <div class="media-content">
                                    <p class="title is-4">John Smith</p>
                                    <p class="subtitle is-6">@johnsmith</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="content">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                                Phasellus nec iaculis mauris. <a>@bulmaio</a>.
                                <a href="#">#css</a> <a href="#">#responsive</a>
                                <br>
                                <time datetime="2016-1-1">11:09 PM - 1 Jan 2016</time>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
                <article class="column is-5">
                    <div class="card is-fullheight">
                        <div class="card-image">
                            <figure class="image is-4by3">
                                <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png" alt="Placeholder image">
                            </figure>
                        </div>
                        <div class="card-content">
                            <div class="media">
                                <div class="media-left">
                                    <figure class="image is-48x48">
                                        <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/96x96.png"
                                            alt="Placeholder image">
                                    </figure>
                                </div>
                                <div class="media-content">
                                    <p class="title is-4">John Smith</p>
                                    <p class="subtitle is-6">@johnsmith</p>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="content">
                                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                                Phasellus nec iaculis mauris. <a>@bulmaio</a>.
                                <a href="#">#css</a> <a href="#">#responsive</a>
                                <br>
                                <time datetime="2016-1-1">11:09 PM - 1 Jan 2016</time>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </article>
            </div
```

The height of the two columns differ. The image of column is-7 is a lot bigger.

Comment: How do you want the bigger image to behave when it has the same height as the smaller one? Should the width still be `100%`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bulma scales the images according to the column width. Therefore the height gets automatically adjusted, when the width differs.

You can simply set a fixed height for the image as well as the `.card-image` class, but keep in mind, that this will scale the images and affect the aspect ratio (I don't know, if thats the wanted result):

```css
.card .card-image,
.card .card-image .image img {
  height: 200px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bulma/0.7.5/css/bulma.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="columns is-fullheight">
  <article class="column is-7">
    <div class="card is-fullheight">
      <div class="card-image">
        <figure class="image is-4by3">
          <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png" alt="Placeholder image">
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <div class="media">
          <div class="media-left">
            <figure class="image is-48x48">
              <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/96x96.png" alt="Placeholder image">
            </figure>
          </div>
          <div class="media-content">
            <p class="title is-4">John Smith</p>
            <p class="subtitle is-6">@johnsmith</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus nec iaculis mauris. <a>@bulmaio</a>.
          <a href="#">#css</a> <a href="#">#responsive</a>
          <br>
          <time datetime="2016-1-1">11:09 PM - 1 Jan 2016</time>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article class="column is-5">
    <div class="card is-fullheight">
      <div class="card-image">
        <figure class="image is-4by3">
          <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/1280x960.png" alt="Placeholder image">
        </figure>
      </div>
      <div class="card-content">
        <div class="media">
          <div class="media-left">
            <figure class="image is-48x48">
              <img src="https://bulma.io/images/placeholders/96x96.png" alt="Placeholder image">
            </figure>
          </div>
          <div class="media-content">
            <p class="title is-4">John Smith</p>
            <p class="subtitle is-6">@johnsmith</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Phasellus nec iaculis mauris. <a>@bulmaio</a>.
          <a href="#">#css</a> <a href="#">#responsive</a>
          <br>
          <time datetime="2016-1-1">11:09 PM - 1 Jan 2016</time>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </article>
  </div
```

Comment: Thank you. The aspect ratio does not matter because I can work around it in Wagtail.